# Access Session data in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

```
 $username = $this->input->post('username');
$password = $this->input->post('password');
$result = $this->AccountModel->login($username,$password);
if($result){
foreach($result as $row){
$loggedin = array('Admin_name' => $row['username'], 'is_loggedin' => TRUE);
$this->session->set_userdata($loggedin);
```

How would i be able to access `['Admin_name']` and `['is_loggedin']` without having to run this code and running a foreach loop `$this->session->all_userdata()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From "Retrieving Session Data" section of Session Class docs:

> Any piece of information from the session array is available using the following function:
>
> $this->session->userdata('item');

So you want:

```
$this->session->userdata('Admin_name');
```

The docs are your friend ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $this->session->userdata('Admin_name');
 $this->session->userdata('is_loggedin');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access as below:

```
$Admin_name = $this->session->userdata('Admin_name');
```

For session library, please check the CI User guide on [sessions](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Answer (score 0):

u can access it by using this line

```
$this->session->userdata['Admin_name'];
```

it should work ..if it dosen't ..just print the session variables using any of the line below

```
echo '<pre>';print_r($this->session->all_userdata());exit;
echo '<pre>';var_dump($this->session->all_userdata());exit;
```

once u see the structure of userdata ..u can easily access any session variables in there just like any other array ..just use

$this->session->userdata['array_key'];